# Model with name does not exist issue sencha touch 2

Tags: xml, model, sencha-touch-2

I have just recently started working with Sencha Touch 2. I am having problem in reading XML data.
error:

```
 Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.data.Store#setModel] Model with name "MyApp2.model.TabBarModel" does not exist.
```

What am I missing?

model :

```
    Ext.define("MyApp2.model.TapBarModel", {
   extend: "Ext.data.Model",
  config: {
type:'tree',
fields: [
{name: 'id', type: 'auto',mapping:'module.id'}
   ]
} 
      });
```

the store :

```
  Ext.define("MyApp2.store.TabBarStore", {
extend: "Ext.data.Store",
requires: ["Ext.data.proxy.JsonP","Ext.data.reader.Xml"],
config: {
    model: "MyApp2.model.TabBarModel",
    autoLoad: true,
    id: 'TabBarStr',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://mysite.com/api/applications/894/config?format=jsonp&appviewer=1&lang=fr&access_token=' + token,
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'application',
            record:'module'
        }
    }
}
  });
```

My file  :

```
 {"status":"ok","config":"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n
 <application id=\"4\" name=\"name\" > 
 <modules>
 <module id=\"32\" >
 <\/module>
  .....
  <\/modules>
    <\/application>\n"}
```

Comment: nopp ,it doesnt work , i think that my model is not compatible with my json(xml) file

Comment: Why do you wrap xml in a JSON-element btw? That's just ridiculous. And it's also the reason why this isn't working..

Comment: i showed u my file , its a json file that content xml configurations , so how can i access to the xml content using json ? ...its a remote web service that i have to use , i need to find a way to access to all attributes ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading a JSON-file, not XML. One of the JSON-objects happens to be some stringified XML, but it doesn't change the fact that you're reading JSON.

You either change the proxy to read json, and handle the result correctly.
Or (which I strongly recommend) change your remote webservice to either return JSON or XML, not XML in JSON or something.

Try something like this:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url: yourUrl,
    params: {
        ...
    },
    success: function(result) {
        var xml = result.config;
        //Parse xml here
        Ext.getStore('TabBarStore').add(yourNewXmlStuffInAnArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant change my remote webservice , i want to get the json response , and getting the config as a string & then parsing it to xml is this possible on sencha touch ?that's how they proceed on the android app ..

Comment: That is possible on Sencha. But why are you using Sencha if there already is an Android App?

Comment: they need an html5 appviewer , for other devices ..can u give me some help plz ?

Comment: Thank u :) , do u mean by yourNewXmlStuffInAnArray the variable xml ?

Comment: @Rob I am not loading any data from json or xml file its hard coded in store but still i am getting this error message
Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.data.Store#setModel] Model with name "ContactItem" does not exist.